# How do I plot a barplot using ggplot2 that differentiates subgroups by color for every year-observation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
year  region  value

2000  Asia       15
2000  Europe     13
2000  America    17
2001  Asia       20
2001  Europe     19
2001  America    25
```

I need to plot a bar graph with year on the x-axis and value on the y-axis, using colors to differentiate the various regions.

I tried plotting it using ggplot2 like this:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = region)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(6))
```

I am able to differentiate the groups by their color, however I get that the groups are stacked for every year, while I would want them to be side by side. How can I do it?

I tried also this:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = region)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(6))
```

but everything becomes a mess, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

`scale_fill_gradientn()` is for continuous variables, but `region` is discrete (categorical). You can use `scale_fill_manual()` to specify your colors instead. Also, you can change `year` to a factor to avoid values like `2000.5` appearing on the x axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data$year <- factor(my_data$year)

ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = region)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = topo.colors(6))
```

[image]